# Calling base constructors not working c#

Tags: c#, constructor, radix

I have the following code returning the error " 'object' does not contain a constructor that takes x arguments." on the line trying to call the base constructor.

**Solution 1, project 1**

```
namespace Project.Sub.A
{
  internal class Foo
  {
    internal Foo(int a, long b) {}

  }
}
```

**Solution 1,project 2**

```
namespace Project.Sub.B{
  internal class Bar : Foo
  {
    internal Bar(int a, long b,long c) :base(a,b+c) {}

  }
}
```

I have NO idea why this does not want to work. Could be my namespaces configured incorrectly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`internal` access is per *assembly*, not namespace.

Because the constructor in the base class is declared `internal`, it is not accessible to the subclass in the other project.  Try changing it to `protected internal`, or just `protected`.

**update**

Just noticed that the base class is also `internal`.  You will need to make it `public` if you want it to be seen in the second project.  Or, you can add `[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("Project2")]` in `AssemblyInfo.cs` in Project1.  (I wouldn't personally recommend this option, though.)

Comment: How do you know its in another project?

Comment: @Jon because he says so... Solution 1, Project 2.

Comment: @Vort3x Those namespaces don't imply anything!

Comment: @SteveCzetty Thanks, public solved it. I will accept in 8 minutes.

Comment: @Jon Yes its too vague, that is why it was stated explicitly as well :)

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of confounding issues here.

- First, your classes are defined as internal in two separate projects. `internal` means that a class is only visible within its own assembly and not to client code outside of the assembly. Foo should be public so that it can be used in other assemblies
- If you make class Foo visible outside of the assembly then you will have to reference that assembly from the project that contains class Bar
- And you will have to make sure that the namespaces are referenced properly as well

Answer (score 2):

internal means `visible to other classes in the current assembly`

Because you're defining your second class in a second project, it can't see that base constructor.

Try making both the Foo Class & Constructor `protected` instead or `internal`.

Answer (score 2):

If it's in a separate project as your question suggests, and your base class is marked internal, then it shouldn't be able to find the entire type, let alone the constructor.

Change Foo' accessor to public.

Comment: Did you mean access modifier? An accessor is a 'get' method isn't it?